# Can I link 3 lists together so one updates the other 2?

Tags: list, sub-site

I have a main site and a Wiki Home page. Then, I have 2 subsites with their own Wiki Homepages. I have the same Quick Links list on all 3 pages--they are identical.

Can I link them all so when I change the list on the main site Home page, they all change? Otherwise when a link needs to be updated, I have to do triple the work.

Please advise!

Best,
Silv

Answer (score 0):

In the same site collection ? Yes Using a list workflow by doing:

Create item and set item

Answer (score 0):

you can try approach export the list as webpart using SharePoint designer approach as display in video below:
https://wonderlaura.com/2011/03/01/video-show-a-list-or-library-on-another-site/

Hope it helps